# How do I convert a date stored in UTC to the user's current locale in PHP?

Tags: localization, datetime

I have a date stored in the database in UTC.

```
2016-01-13 09:01:16
```

I can query the database and output this date just fine. But it outputs in the date in the wrong timezone.

**How do I adjust a date from the database into the current user's locale?**

I believe this involves using `craft()->timezone` at some point, with some method, but I have not had any luck. I'm retrieving the date with the query builder:

```
$rows = craft()->db->createCommand()
         ->select('dateCreated')
         ->from('mytable')
         ->queryAll();
```

**Bonus points**: sometimes I have multiple dates, so I need to modify all dates I get back into the right timezone.

**More bonus points**: at what point in the process is the best point to modify the date into the right timezone? In MySQL query? In PHP? In Twig?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code used in the past.

```
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(craft()->getTimeZone());
$newdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME, $mysqlDate, $timezone);
```

I have typically done this before assigning to a model.